# Perform an action after driver initialization during boot

Tags: c++, c, windows-ce

I would like to perform an action on the device drivers in the system after they initialize during boot-up. I would like to do this from my own application that would not be part of any existing driver. Is there a way to check when a driver is done with its initialization from my application so I can do what I would like to do. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is unclear.  Control from where?  Is your question better phrased like this?

> I would like to perform an action on every driver in the system after they initialize from my own, separate driver/application/etc. code.  This code would not be part of any existing driver.

If that's what you're after then no, there is no inherent way to do this. If it's your own OS you could probably clone and modify the busenum driver (`%WINCEROOT%\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\DRIVERS\BUSENUM`) which is responsible for loading drivers, but I'm far from convinced that's a good idea.  What problem, exactly, are you trying to solve here?

***EDIT***

For further detail on the BUSENUM driver "option", in BusEnum.cpp, starting at line 260 is the method `BusEnum::ActivateAllChildDrivers`.  This method is responsible for loading each of the drivers in the driver registry.  At line 293 you'll see this:

```
pCurDevice->LoadDevice();
```

You would then insert your code right after that.

Comment: Thanks @ctacke. I rephrased the question for better clarity. If I would like to modify the busenum driver, I wonder how I would know when the device driver is done initializing. Because, as I mentioned above, I would like to perform an action on the driver as soon as it is initialized.

Comment: Thanks again @ctacke. This looks like an option. I was also looking at `RequestDeviceNotifications` and was wondering if that can help here. MSDN says that "this function requests notifications for the appearance and disappearance of device interfaces". I was wondering if I can register for device notifications, waitforsingleobject on the messageQueue handle to perform my action. Not sure what exactly the "appearance" part means in MSDN definition though. Does it include loading the DLL and initializing it. Any suggestions?